# What's the Ubuntu's default shell?

Tags: ubuntu, shell

What's the Ubuntu's default shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regular users it's Bash. For root it's Dash (sh).

Answer (score 0):

In some distributions you do not have the bash shell. But you can enable that using the procedure below:

1) Check if 'bash' is available

```
$ bash
```

2) If not, (you encounter an command not found error) install that:

```
$ pkg_add -r -v bash
```

3) Change the default shell to bash of any user:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

4) To check for the bash installation location, you can type:

```
$ which bash
```

You can refer [my blog](http://gettechgo.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/bash-shell-for-ubuntu/), for more information.